# Как продублировать функции php

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть функция в functions.php

```
 // load more function by ajax
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

function load_posts_by_ajax_callback(){
  check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
  $paged= $_POST['page'];

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'materials',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' =>$paged,
    'cat' => 40,
  );

  $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($my_posts-> have_posts()) { ?>

    <?php
      while($my_posts-> have_posts()){
        $my_posts-> the_post(); ?>

       <?php the_title(); ?>

    <?php  }
    ?>
<?php  }

wp_die();
}
```

и есть скрипт в footer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    var page =2;
    jQuery(function($){
        // init isotope
        var $grid = $('.grid');
        $grid.isotope({
          // options
          itemSelector: '.item',
          percentPosition: true,
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function(e){

          var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
          };

          $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
            if (response != '') {
              var $answer = $(response);

              //append items to grid
              $grid.append($answer)
              .isotope('appended', $answer);

              // layaout on imagesLoaded
              $grid.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $grid.isotope('layout');
              });
              page++;
            } else{
              $('.loadmore').text("ВСЕ ЗАГРУЖЕНО");
              $('.loadmore').attr("disabled", true);
              $('.loadmore').css("borderColor", "gray");
              $('.loadmore').css("color", "gray");
            }
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

мне нужно таких 5 функций в каждой функции разные 'cat' => 40, как их переделать, я просто в php не разбираюсь...

Comment: Тогда наверное имеет смысл сделать таким образом чтобы параметр `cat` был динамическим и передавался например в аякс запросе с фронта. Если я верно понял то что Вам нужно. Можно повесить какой-то data атрибут или при [wp_localize_script()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_localize_script) передавать его.

Comment: а можно как то функцию переименовать что бы разные имена были и фоотер их подхватит, я просто не могу понять как фоотер определяет эту функцию

Comment: Это будет глупо. Вы хотите 5 раз продублировать функцию просто чтобы менять ID категории, Вам не кажется такой подход не очень продуктивным? Понимает по `action` который указан у Вас в объекте data.

Comment: мне в любом случае нужно дублировать ее потому что я буду другой тип поста использовать

Comment: А не проще передавать тип поста и ID категории (по-сути 2 строки), вместо того чтобы дублировать 30+ строк 5 раз ради тех несчастных двух строк?

Comment: можете пример накинуть как передать тип и ID категории для каждой страницы

Comment: Ну точно так же как Вы передаете номер страницы. Только если Вам нужен пост тайп используйте [get_post_type()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post_type) или [get_queried_object()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_queried_object) я просто не знаю где Вы это выводите, тоже самое для категории, Вам нужно получить ее ID, используя тот же `get_queried_object()` в зависимости от обстоятельств.